# checking for duplicate entry on database

Tags: php

```
<?php    
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $error = "";

    if (!empty($_POST["time"])) {
        $time = $_POST["time"];
    } 
    else {
        $error .= "You didn't type in a time. <br />";
    }

    if (empty($error)) {
        $success = header("Location: index.php");
        $sql = "INSERT INTO appointment(time) VALUES('".$time."')";
        $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
?>
<?php
    if (!empty($error)) {
        echo '<p class="error">' . $error . '</p>';
    } else if (!empty($success)) {
        echo $success;
    }
?>
```

I'm having a hard time thinking of a way on how my codes will generate a duplicate entry. What I'm aiming is that whenever a user inputs a time that is already taken and stored in the database it should tell the user to choose another time since it has already been taken.

Comment: so what have you done so far?

Comment: i think i should have an if statement inside if (!empty($_POST["time"])) { //conditions for checking duplicate but i dont have an idea on what to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this might help you :

```
$query = "select time from yourtable where time='".$time ."'";
mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows()>0){
 $error .= "Time  already been taken. <br />";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to select records based on your input:-

> select time from table where time = your_input_time

then count rows you get from query result

```
if(count_rows > 0) {
  // then go back for input again 
}
else {
  // insert row.
}
```